# How does Machinarium handle save games?

Tags: machinarium

Does anybody know how Machinarium handles save states?  I put about a half hour into it the other day, clicked 'Save,' and then quit.

Loaded it up today to continue and lo and behold, my save game was nowhere to be found.

One caveat is that I don't have internet access currently...is it possible that it syncs save states with the Steam cloud?

Comment: It doesn't use the Steam cloud. As to if it uses a different one, I don't know, but I wouldn't expect so.

Comment: I had a similar problem where it deleted my save, was rather annoying. To say the least I probably won't get around to finishing it for awhile because of this.

Comment: That evokes sadness in me.  I was enjoying the simplistic point&click style too.

Comment: I believe the Steam version of Machinarium was reworked to no longer use flash, so the answer may have changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I may have found the answer.  I didn't realize that it makes use of the Flash player data directory instead of somewhere more logical, like the Documents or Steam folder.

From the [Machinarium forums](http://forum.amanita-design.net/index.php?topic=358.0):

```
Windows:
"%AppData%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\{RANDOMWORD}\localhost\{PATH_TO_MACHINARIUM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\machinarium.exe\Machinarium.sol"

Mac:
"~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/{RANDOMWORD}/localhost/{PATH_TO_MACHINARIUM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}/machinarium.exe/Machinarium.sol"

Linux/Unix:
"~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/{RANDOMWORD}/localhost/{PATH_TO_MACHINARIUM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}/machinarium.exe/Machinarium.sol"
```

Long story short...if you are regularly using something like Ccleaner to clear out your temp files, then your save games will get blown away.

Comment: Machanarium is essentially a Flash game, and one of the default location CCleaner will clear is the Flash local object data, which most Flash games use to hold their save files.

Comment: True, but if its being released as a full-game as part of Steam, I would have hoped that the developers would put users save game files in a non-volatile environment.

Comment: It was originally released as a stand-alone game, then added to Steam later on down the road (sometime around the Humble Indie Bundle 2 release). It doesn't have any Steam integration like some other games might: achievements, cloud saves, etc.

Comment: Let's say I'm clearing my browsing history though. Will erasing cookies do the same thing? Will erasing the cache do the same thing? Where does Flash player data store itself in?

Answer (score 3):

it's straight forward guys. When you save game and quit, navigate to shared objects/machinarium folder and locate machinarium.sol file. Copy and paste to desktop. When you restart, exit and copy and replace file in same folder (this has reverted back to startinf point). Relaunch game and bingo - sorted. Bit of a pain but only takes 10 seconds and worth it.

Comment: you could improve that by writing a batch file that copies the backed up machinarium.sol (from some better place than desktop please), then starts machinarium and after that quits makes a new backup

Comment: too much hassle to write a batch file; so easy the way I have described. Doesn't have to be desktop, can be anywhere but is convenient and quick.