# Why are my flash game saves getting erased?

Tags: technical-issues, flash

After installing stand-alone flash games such as [Machinarium](http://www.machinarium.net/), [Dino Run SE](http://www.pixeljam.com/dinorunse/), and [Space Rubbish](http://www.pixeljam.com/dinorubbish/) (all of which are great games by the way) I find that my game saves keep disappearing.

I have read how cleaning programs like CCleaner can [have](http://forum.piriform.com/index.php?showtopic=24995) [this](http://machinarium.net/forum/index.php?topic=359.0) [effect](http://www.giantbomb.com/vvvvvv/61-29745/warningccleaner-deletes-savegames/35-383537/). I have CCleaner installed, but do not have it set to run automatically. I have found that whenever I start and then quit IE, my saves disappear. I also run Firefox, but it seems to have no effect on my saves.

My question is: **How can I stop IE from deleting these local Flash caches?**

As a side note: Do any other browsers have this sort of behaviour by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Machinarium save games](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/machinarium-save-games)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you allow flash to save data to your hard drive.

Right click the flash game and select Setting (or Global settings). Under the "Storage" tab, make sure "Allow sites to save information on this computer" is checked.

Adobe also has a page you can use to set flash settings: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html

Comment: These are stand-alone flash games, i don't play them in my browser.

Comment: @RedriderX It doesn't matter. All Flash files use those global settings. You may need to run the game in your browser to set the domain specific settings though.

Comment: Flash saves its data to: %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects Does this folder get cleared after you exit IE?

Comment: Make sure "Delete browsing history on exit" is not checked in IE.

Comment: I unchecked the "Delete browsing history on exit" option in IE's internet options and that has done the job. I will now use CCleaner for cookie removal BUT will also make an exception for local data, thanks.

Comment: BTW you can keep the storage policy as is (ask / block all), but specifically allow it for certain sites.  For local games, the "site" is `local`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you got IE set to "Delete browsing history on exit" and, in the Delete options, got the "**Cookies**" option selected?

This will delete the game saves if they are stored in cookies.

Comment: Flash stores it's own cookies and data separate from any browser's data.

Answer (score 0):

Asked this a while ago [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/machinarium-save-games).

Basically if you have any sort of tool installed to clean up your browser temp files on exit, then you'll blow away your save games.  @CheeseSucker's comments are valid.  I have the issue while running BetterPrivacy in FF.