# How do I save progress on local Flash games?

Tags: flash

Before Adobe Flash completely shut down I downloaded a bunch of `.swf` files along with the Flash Player application so I could play them once it all went offline.

But after playing a game, I'm not sure how long it is, but the progress I made would eventually disappear no matter what the game.

I'm not sure if it's different since I'm not doing it in a browser, but how do I save the progress for these games permanently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my flash game saves getting erased?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32257/why-are-my-flash-game-saves-getting-erased). note: most likely cause: a browser (extension) is deleting the browser cache for the 'localhost' site.